# Why my iPhone app is not shown on iPad App Store?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, app-store

I have released a new app, Il Cervellone, in my Country (ITALY).

My app is an iPhone/iPod touch app, but, usually also iPad devices can installs iPhone application but my app is not shown in iPad App Store.
Why?
How can i solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maybe you have 6.0.1 on iPad...

[iOS 6 with iPad: App Store search won't show iPhone Apps if search query has no results for iPad Apps](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4478440?start=0&tstart=0)

Answer (score 0):

You must Change Your App Store Account Location :

1. Tap "Settings" from the main menu of your iOS device.
2. Tap "iTunes & App Stores"
3. Tap "View Apple ID."
4. Enter your user name and password.
5. Tap the space underneath "Change Country or Region."
6. Select the region where you released your app"
7. Tap "Done."